# Android: Acomodar CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android

Coloqué un `CoordinatorLayout` pero según yo ya acomode como se debe de ver pero lo que pasa es que el `TextView` y el `GridView` que tengo se colocan uni encima del otro, el `coordinatorLayout` lo requiero en la parte superior y abajo el `TextView` y `GridView`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tritonix.scotproyect.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.sample.foo.usingcoordinatorlayout.FabAndSnackbarActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:title="Hola">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/pic1"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="Bienvenido"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/pic1"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/data_checkin" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="300dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu
        android:id="@+id/arcmenu_android_example_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu_color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:menu_open="arc_right"
        app:menu_scr="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/home"
            android:tint="#FFF"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/picture"
            android:tint="#FFF"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    </com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Jorge te agradesco por estar siempre muy atento, ya pude solucionarlo, lo que pasa es que lo estaba colocando mal, donde se deve colocar mi textVies y GridView es dentro de NestedScrollView y ya lo demas sale sobrando. Muchas Gracias te apresio.

Comment: Agrega tu solución para que otros usuarios puedan enterarse!.

Comment: Si deja lo subo :D

Comment: Listo Jorge ya la publique y gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi problema ya quedo resuelto, lo que pasa es que estaba utilizando de manera incorrecta el CoordinationLayout.
Este CoordinationLayout contiene un GridView que coloque dentro de un LinearLayout, aclaro que todo mi contenido yo lo colocare dentro de mi LinearLayout ya que en mi ejemplo de arriba todo estava mal ordenado y sobravan muchas cosas.
Este es mi ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:title="Bienvenido">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@drawable/pic2"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/data_checkin" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeScot"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="300dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_picture"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/picture"
    android:tint="#FFF"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_home"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/home"
    android:tint="#FFF"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|fill_horizontal|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```